# The triggered DAG can't get params from TriggerDagRunOperator

Tags: airflow

I've tried to trigger another dag with some paramters in a TriggerDagRunOperator, but in the triggered dag, the dag_run object is always None.

In the TriggerDagRunOperator, the message param is added into dag_run_obj's payload.

```py
def conditionally_trigger(context, dag_run_obj):
if context['params']['condition_param']:
    dag_run_obj.payload = {'message': context['params']['message']}
    pp.pprint(dag_run_obj.payload)
    return dag_run_obj


trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='test_trigger_dagrun',
    trigger_dag_id="example_trigger_target_dag",
    python_callable=conditionally_trigger,
    params={'condition_param': True, 'message': 'Hello World'},
    dag=dag,
)
```

I expected the triggered DAG could get it using kwargs['dag_run'].conf['message']) but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```py
def run_this_func(ds, **kwargs):
print("Remotely received value of {} for key=message".
      format(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['message']))


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_this',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_this_func,
    dag=dag,
)
```

The dag_run object in kwargs is None

```
INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): run_this> on 2019-01-18 16:10:18 
INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-18 16:10:27,007] {models.py:1433} ERROR - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'conf'
INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
INFO - Subtask:   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1390, in run
INFO - Subtask:     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
INFO - Subtask:   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 80, in execute
INFO - Subtask:     return_value = self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
INFO - Subtask:   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py", line 52, in run_this_func
INFO - Subtask:     print("Remotely received value of {} for key=message".format(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['message']))
INFO - Subtask: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'conf'
```

I also printed out the kwargs and indeed the 'dag_run' object is None.
The dags are sample code in Airflow so I'm not sure what happened.
Anybody knows the reason?

```
INFO - Subtask: kwargs: {u'next_execution_date': None, u'dag_run': None, u'tomorrow_ds_nodash': u'20190119', u'run_id': None, u'dag': <DAG: example_trigger_target_dag>, u'prev_execution_date': None, ...
```

BTW, If I trigger the DAG from CLI, it worked:

```
$ airflow trigger_dag 'example_trigger_target_dag' -r 'run_id' --conf '{"message":"test_cli"}'
```

Logs:

```
INFO - Subtask: kwargs: {u'next_execution_date': None, u'dag_run': <DagRun example_trigger_target_dag @ 2019-01-18 ...

INFO - Subtask: Remotely received value of test_cli for key=message
```

Comment: Which airflow version is it? I can run that example dag from the airflow 1.10.1 web UI.

Comment: it's 1.8.2 I thought it should work. But couldn't find the reason

Comment: OK, I've tried 1.10.1 and this Operator worked. So not sure why 1.8.2 has this un-work example